# PySide2 UI stops responding when entering a while loop after showing it

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, pyside2, qt-signals

I'm having trouble where my `QtWidget` stops responding if I try to use a while loop after calling the `widget.show()` method for the `QtWidget` object. I initially thought the issue was in how I was using the signals and slots. I had created my own signal with `new_data = Signal(float)` and I was sampling data at an interval established by a `time.sleep()` call within that while loop and emitting the new_data signal each time the data was sampled. That was connected to a method in my `QtWidget` that just set the text of a label in the `QtWidget` to display the new data.

However, after some testing I found that if I ONLY try to `print("in loop")` inside that while loop, I get the same behavior. The QtWidget object stops responding. What is the proper way to update PySide2 interface at a periodic interval from outside the interface object? Can I perhaps run the interface as a process and feed it with updated data with a queue? I imaging that is possible, but am having trouble finding an example. The interface is only one piece of this application primarily made in Python and I will have multiple processes and multiple queues besides the Qt interface. Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile, QObject, Signal, Slot
import time
import NI9213 

class MyDaq(QObject):
    new_daq_data = Signal(float)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        daq_channels = "cDAQ1Mod2/ai0"
        self.daq = NI9213.NI9213(channels=daq_channels)

    def sample_daq(self):
        data = self.daq.read_all()
        self.new_daq_data.emit(data)

class DigitalDisplay(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        #Initialize the QWidget object used to create the user interface
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        #Load the user interface
        designer_file = QFile("signal_digital_display.ui")
        designer_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(designer_file, self)
        designer_file.close()

        #Add title to the UI window
        self.setWindowTitle("Digital Display")

        self.mode = 'run'

        self.ui.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stopMode)

        self.sampling_period = 0.1

    @Slot(float)     
    def refresh_data(self, data):
        self.ui.label.setText(str(data))

    def stopMode(self):
        self.mode = 'stop'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    digital_display = DigitalDisplay()
    digital_display.show()

##    data = MyDaq()
##    data.new_daq_data.connect(digital_display.refresh_data)
##
    while(digital_display.mode=='run'):
        print("after display.show")

##        data.sample_daq()
        time.sleep(digital_display.sampling_period)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have an infinite loop before you start the Qt event loop.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  # [1]
    digital_display = DigitalDisplay() 
    digital_display.show()  # [2]

    while(digital_display.mode=='run'):
        print("after display.show")
        time.sleep(digital_display.sampling_period)  # [3]

    sys.exit(app.exec_()) # [4]
```

[1] This creates the QApplication object. It does not start the event loop yet.

[2] Create your widget and open a new window to display it. The operating system will create events for the window, but they have no effect on the application itself until we start the event loop.

[3] `digital_display.mode` will never change. This is an infinite loop and Python will never advance past this point.

[4] **Here** we start the application event loop and close the process once the application has finished. But we never get here.

What you should do instead is to create a `QTimer` on the `DigitalDisplay` widget that periodically fires a signal that can be connected to `data.sample_daq`.